# jenkins - the Publish Over SSH plugin not displayed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working with Jenkins and I want to install the Publish Over SSH Plugin, but I didn't see the plugin not in the Available Tab, and not in the Installed Tab.

Is it possible to install this plugin in another way?

Comment: Correction: I want to install the Publish Over SSH plugin and not the Publisher Over SSH plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin was probably pulled from plugin repository due to an extensive list of [unresolved Security Issues](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2022-01-12/#SECURITY-2287).

If prepared to accept the risk, you can download the latest release from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/releases/latest), then [manually upload](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation).

Update: for some reason, the plugin mainteners only github release the source tarballs and not the corresponding hpi/jpi. Found it in [the archives](https://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/publish-over-ssh/latest/). Go up a dir for earler versions, up two for over plugins.

Update 2: Shortly after this answer was posted, the vulnerabilities in the plugin were resolved and a [new release made - 1.23](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/#releases) (Feb 11, 2022), thereby making the plugin available again for download. While the answer has now been "accepted" a year later, the guidance is applicable to any revoked plugin: got to [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci) and download the plugin from the GitHub release. Links to source are found on the the "links" section of the [plugins site for each plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh) .

Comment: I have installed Jenkins on an Amazon Linux machine.
I didn't succeed to upload manually the Publish over ssh plugins.
Could you describe me with details the differents steps to upload the plugin.
I am beginning in Jenkins

Comment: You just download the jar from GitHub release folder to your desktop using browser, then log into Jenkins using browser and put the path to the jar in the upload box. It now also takes a URL, so maybe you can combine the two steps and pit the GitHub release URL there? Oh, I see the releases has no artifact (jpi). Might be an issue. I was expecting to see hpi/jpi like for [TFS](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/releases/tag/tfs-5.157.1)

Comment: Found the archives. Updated A.

Comment: There's [hope for you](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-dev/c/uJAFEKYOnPc) yet. @motto-c, an upvote and / or answered would be nice :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the plugin was installed after I logged out and back in. But I don't know why, because I did it several before and the plugin didn''t install then.
I'm sorry thst i forgot to update tou.

Answer (score 1):

Manual installation :

0- donwload source code zip file from here under:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin.git

1- install mvn on your local machine if not yet.
2- open terminal in the folder (source code folder which is downloaded from Github (step 0)
3- Run mvn compile, after that mvn package--> will generate target folder with necessary files.(.jar, .hpi)
4- inside the generated folder target you will find .hpi file
5- in Jenkins UI go to manage Jenkins -> Plugin management -> in the second section UI based upload, upload .hpi file from target folder and hit upload. after successful upload a window appears where you can restart jenkins - changes will take effect after restarting.

You will successfully find the plugin installed under "installed" tab. With security warning. which is obviously not to be used in a production environment.
let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the plugin was installed after I logged out and login again.
But I saw this only after logging out and logging in several times because each time I logged out and logged in, the plugin was still not installed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).