# deploy static code to apache httpd server automatically

Tags: apache, jenkins, deployment

I have a static website that I would like to deploy to my Apache httpd server using Jenkins or any other methods.

my code base available in GitHub.
My files in server has to be updated in path: /var/www/html

Comment: You need to pur more [work into asking your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you expect some help. What have you tried so far, issues encountered, etc.?

Comment: I tried with Jenkins to publish over ssh. ssh plugin is disconnected no longer available to download.

Comment: Can't believe how [popular this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779329/598141). Pls upvote

Comment: I have html files in Github. When ever new commit is made, I need to push the files to Linux server in to a specific location. eg. var/www/html. I tried with Jenkins with publish over ssh, but plugin is not available now.

Answer (score 0):

you could set Jenkins to Poll your Repository in Github. You will need to set up the integrations between Github and Jenkins so Jenkins can poll your Repo for changes. Then you can use a Copy tool of your choice, like Rsync or SCP, and run them in the Jenkins Script to copy the file to your server.

Jenkins Polling and SCM Management - https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/jenkins-job-tutorial/